# Get & Set problem when wanting to return name + text + actual value

Tags: c#

I was trying to make a program that would take person's name, age and what job he/she would like to work, and i have setted my job attribute in class as private, because i wanted to use get & set to get it back in return, but for some reason, i am only getting value as return, and nothing else:

```
using System;

namespace Exercise_Project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Apply for job application
            Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter how old are you: ");
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (age < 18)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are too young to work!");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Which job would you like to work: Programmer, Magician, Baker - ");
                string job = Console.ReadLine();
                Employee Person = new Employee(name, age, job);
                Console.WriteLine(Person.Job);

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class Employee
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;
        private string job;

        public Employee(string aName, int aAge, string aJob)
        {
            name = aName;
            age = aAge;
            job = aJob;
        }

        public string Job
        {
            get
            {
                return job;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value=="Programmer" || value== "Magician" || value == "Baker")
                {
                    job = name + ", welcome to your new job as " + value;
                }
                else
                {
                    job = name + ", you don't have a job!";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never use the `Job` setter.  You only use the constructor and the getter:

```
Employee Person = new Employee(name, age, job);
Console.WriteLine(Person.Job);
```

You could use the setter before using the getter:

```
Employee Person = new Employee(name, age, job);
Person.Job = job;
Console.WriteLine(Person.Job);
```

Though that's a bit redundant after already using the constructor.  You could also have the constructor internally use the setter:

```
public Employee(string aName, int aAge, string aJob)
{
    name = aName;
    age = aAge;
    Job = aJob; // Note the use of Job instead of job
}
```